# Find Logger for PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for logger for PHP like log4j. can you suggest me witch logger that I can use ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is a port - Log4Php, http://logging.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

[log4php](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/index.html)?

One of the [family](http://logging.apache.org/) of loggers

Answer (score 0):

PEAR logging class is pretty nice and simple. 
There is no need to configure things via xml and there are no other dependencies.
You can download and simply drop in pear package [PEAR log](http://pear.php.net/package/Log/download) (no need to install it via PEAR or Pyrus).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very popular logging layer library for PHP - https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog
It provides many integrations, including sending data to https://www.loggly.com/ or https://sentry.io/welcome/

Also, many logging services, like https://phplogger.com/, support Monlog in one form or another